# How to put Mozenda scraped data into Meteor app?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, web-scraping

Lets say I used Mozenda to scrape a bunch of data from a site, and I want to display it on my Meteor app. How do I do that? Would I try to push it into a specific Mongo database that is liked to the Meteor app, and how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Scrape the data and insert it into a collection which you can then display